# else if statement across multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to apply the else if function across multiple columns in the following sample dataset:

```
dput(data_compressed)
structure(list(Day = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), act1_001 = c("leisure", 
"leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", 
"leisure", "leisure", "leisure"), act1_002 = c("leisure", "leisure", 
"leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", 
"leisure", "leisure"), act1_003 = c("leisure", "leisure", "leisure", 
"leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", 
"leisure"), act1_004 = c("leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", 
"leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure"
), act1_005 = c("leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", 
"leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure", "leisure")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Logic of my elseif codes: If the two conditions (i) Day=1 and (ii) every column that starts with "act1" is coded with "leisure", then print "leisure1". If Day=0 and act1=leisure, then print "leisure0". The same logic applies to the remaining statements.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

if(data$Day == 1 & data$across(starts_with("act1")) == "leisure") {
  print("leisure1")
} else if(
  data$Day == 0 & data$across(starts_with("act1")) == "leisure") {
  print("leisure0")
} else if(
  data$Day == 1 & data$across(starts_with("act1")) == "work") {
  print("work1")
} else if(
  data$Day == 0 & data$across(starts_with("act1")) == "work") {
  print("work0")
} else if(
  data$Day == 1 & data$across(starts_with("act1")) == "home") {
  print("home1")
} else {
  print("home0")
}
```

This is the error message:

Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `across`.Error: attempt to apply non-function

Comment: The code you provided is not sufficient to recreate the data frame `data` - what is your `data` supposed to look like? Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(data)` and also include the desired output from the input data? `across` and `starts_with` are from the `dplyr` and `tidyselect` packages - are you wanting a tidyverse solution? Also, what is the logic of your if/else statements? Could you explain the logic in more detail using words rather than just code?

Comment: is `c(a,a,b,d,d)` supposed to be `c("a","a","b","d","d")`, or do you have variables named `a`, `b`, and `d` in your environment that contain something else?

Comment: Your use of `data$across` suggests you have more experience in other programming languages with `$`-dispatch on methods (or such) ... but that does not work that way in R. If you're intending to use `dplyr::across`, then ... that is also not correct usage of it. Please [edit] your question with the output from `dput(data)` (this sample data) and also add (as already requested) your intended output given that sample data (perhaps from `dput(.)`, or at least the console output of the desired result). Thanks.

Comment: While giving the _hint_ of data structure is being done in this question, there are two reasons why I ask that you don't do it this way Victoria: (1) we can't use it, since `c(a,a,b,d,d)` doesn't work as you intend; and (2) it is always better if the code/sample-data you give us is what you have tried on your console. Said differently, always try the code/data you give us before submitting the question. When we get unrelated errors, it is either hard to know if that's your underlying problem or if it is just a red-herring/distraction from what problem(s) you're really having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you just mean this?

```r
data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("act1"), ~ paste0(.x, Day)))
#   Day act1_001 act1_002 act1_003 act1_004 act1_005 act1_006 act1_007
# 1   1       a1       b1       d1       a1       a1       b1       b1
# 2   1       a1       a1       b1       a1       d1       a1       b1
# 3   2       b2       b2       a2       b2       d2       b2       b2
# 4   2       d2       b2       d2       d2       b2       d2       d2
# 5   1       d1       d1       a1       d1       a1       b1       d1
```

---

Data

```r
data <- structure(list(Day = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1), act1_001 = c("a", "a", "b", "d", "d"), act1_002 = c("b", "a", "b", "b", "d"), act1_003 = c("d", "b", "a", "d", "a"), act1_004 = c("a", "a", "b", "d", "d"), act1_005 = c("a", "d", "d", "b", "a"), act1_006 = c("b", "a", "b", "d", "b"), act1_007 = c("b", "b", "b", "d", "d")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your logic you want to collapse the number associated with `Day` with the letter in each column. To do this in base R, you could do:

```
act_cols <- grep("act1", names(data)) # identify columns of interest

data[act_cols] <- lapply(data[act_cols], \(x) paste0(unlist(x), unlist(data[1])))
```

Output:

```
#   Day act1_001 act1_002 act1_003 act1_004 act1_005 act1_006 act1_007
# 1   1       a1       b1       d1       a1       a1       b1       b1
# 2   1       a1       a1       b1       a1       d1       a1       b1
# 3   2       b2       b2       a2       b2       d2       b2       b2
# 4   2       d2       b2       d2       d2       b2       d2       d2
# 5   1       d1       d1       a1       d1       a1       b1       d1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using across not correctly. Here is a solution in `tidyverse` using `case_when()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("act1"), names_to = "activity", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(
    Day == 1 & value == "a" ~ "a1",
    Day == 2 & value == "a" ~ "a2",
    Day == 1 & value == "b" ~ "b1",
    Day == 2 & value == "b" ~ "b2",
    Day == 1 & value == "d" ~ "d1",
    .default =  "d2"
  ))

A tibble: 35 × 4
     Day activity value result
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr> 
 1     1 act1_001 a     a1    
 2     1 act1_002 b     b1    
 3     1 act1_003 d     d1    
 4     1 act1_004 a     a1    
 5     1 act1_005 a     a1    
 6     1 act1_006 b     b1    
 7     1 act1_007 b     b1    
 8     1 act1_001 a     a1    
 9     1 act1_002 a     a1    
10     1 act1_003 b     b1    
# ℹ 25 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

data:

```
Day <- c(1,1,2,2,1)
act1_001 <- c("a","a","b","d","d")
act1_002 <- c("b","a","b","b","d")
act1_003 <- c("d","b","a","d","a")
act1_004 <- c("a","a","b","d","d")
act1_005 <- c("a","d","d","b","a")
act1_006 <- c("b","a","b","d","b")
act1_007 <- c("b","b","b","d","d")

data <- data.frame(Day, act1_001, act1_002, act1_003, act1_004, act1_005, act1_006, act1_007)
```